# Any Tips when Raising the Functional Level of a 2003 Domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I will be doing my first DFL rising this evening (from 2003 to 2008 R2). Is there anything worth noting that I should look out for?  Any risks involved? Or server reboots?  I've done a system state backup on two of our operations DC's just in case, but wasn't sure if I should prepare anything else before hand.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising the DFL from 2003 can cause issues with existing Kerberos tickets.  This is due to the password for the krbtgt account is changed.

For most environments, this may be transparent.  Applications/processes would request new tickets.  In rare cases, servers may need to be restarted to restore service.  Usually the canary in the coal mine is Exchange.

More information here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/02/13/considering-updating-your-domain-functional-level-from-windows-2003-read-this.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a lot.  I've marked as the answer, but I also found an article stating to run the below and make sure they are all successful: - repadmin /replsum
- repadmin /showrepl
- repadmin /bridgeheads
- dcdiag /v (checking overall health of the domain)

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much to do. You only need a System State backup of one DC. No reboots are required. Have a read here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/06/14/what-is-the-impact-of-upgrading-the-domain-or-forest-functional-level